# optimizing sql search time

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a question regarding how to optimize my search time through a mySQL database. The entire database is stored in 1 table laid out with these columns: video_link, image_link, description, length, and site. As of right now I have 1,200,000 rows and will be expanding upwards of 10,000,000 when all is said and done. When I run a search query like:

```
SELECT * 
FROM  `VIDEOS` 
WHERE  `DESCRIPTION` LIKE  '%search_string%'
```

it takes 1.3808 seconds to complete. That is not a terrible search time, but when the row count doubles it will be. I should mention that the database is being used on a website and the search bar runs a query on the database and returns the results. Most sites have way more stored and have a faster search time. Is there any way to improve the performance?

Comment: The use of backticks suggests MySQL, so I removed the SQL Server tag.

Comment: Look into the use full text indexing.  It is really the only way to optimize this type of query:  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-search.html.

Comment: You might also want to consider external fulltext search solution like Sphinx or Lucene if you are expecting high traffic. MySQL fulltext performs quite poorly compared to those.

Comment: Looks good Quassnoi but I am using hostgator as a hosting service and I do not think they offer either of those or anything like that lol.

Comment: And Gordon fulltext works very well averages are under 300m/s thanks =)

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX
        fx_videos_description
ON      videos (description);

SELECT  *
FROM    videos
WHERE   MATCH(description, '+search_string' IN BOOLEAN MODE);
```

This only works on MyISAM tables prior to MySQL 5.6

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do the like query you have there you will want to have a full text index on description.

Also in general select * is pretty slow, so if you don't need every column you should trim that down.

Comment: How would I go about trimming that down. If you are searching for a video would you not have to query all the descriptions to try and find a match?

Comment: select * doesn't refer to querying over all the descriptions, it refers to the information you want back.  I don't know how you are applying this but if you don't always need all that information then you shouldn't be querying it from SQL.  Honestly though if you don't have it the full text index should solve most of your performance issues.